# Rotate HTML with JS as in Photoshop's free transform

Tags: javascript, rotation

I need to rotate some html content (let it be a div) by dragging a block inside it with a mouse. The content should rotate around it's center. Look at http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app (drag an element from right to left and drag a circle inside it) for an example. Are there any plugins or solutions in js to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 has some advanced features that support [rotation of arbitrary HTML elements](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/). As far as I know there are no libraries exploiting this to allow what you ask yet.

You may also want to look into SVG, where there are libraries such as [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which can ease working with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below, it have good resol like your requirement, free transform like photoshop or Illustrator also drag the size too..

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/

with regards,
aminahmed